# Is the material behind my wall's surface asbestos?

Tags: asbestos

I'm a bit worried. All the wall is peeled off and its an old house. Just trying to renovate.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A question like this calls for more information. Please revise to list location, age of home, etc.

Comment: Like Isherwood said, age, location of the home would be great as would any other pertinent information (e.g. asbestos used elsewhere in the home...)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We won't be able to give you a definitive answer from out here. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably just plaster. However, a test kit is the only reliable indicator.

Comment: I'm unaware of asbestos having ever been used in a domestic setting as a *loose* wall material, +1 (utility rooms notwithstanding, but that comes in sheets). What would be hard to tell is if it's rock lath or asbestos paneling. If the substrate crumbles like plaster, it's probably plaster. If it doesn't, it's one of the other two. But it doesn't matter if the OP is going to just patch the wall; only if they're going to demo it.